# Is there another way of closing a MongoDB connection outside of this function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have quite a large data set I need to upload from my node.js app to a mongo db, it runs through a `for` loop to get every result. Originally I made the connection to the MongoDB in every loop however this was causing it to crash.

Since I have moved it out of the loop the `db.close()` is causing an issue, if I leave it in the loop it closes the connection (since the connection is not remade in the loop the app crashes):
`MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed`

However if I move it outside of the loop it will get stuck and not leave the loop and continue with other operations.

Does anybody know how I can effectively close down my database connection outside of the `for` loop, only once it has finished iterating?

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydatabase");
    //run sql query to get data

    for(result in sqldata) {

        myobj = {Number: sqldata[result].Num} //<--- this for loop produces 16000 entries

        dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 document inserted");
          db.close(); //<--- this is the issue
    });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `await` the insert operations.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, async (err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydatabase");
    let results = [];
    //run sql query to get data

    for(result in sqldata) {
        myobj = {Number: sqldata[result].Num} //<--- this for loop produces 16000 entries

        results.push(
            new Promise((resolve) => {
                dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, (err, res) => {
                    console.log(err ? 'Document not inserted' : 'Document inserted');
                    resolve();
                })
            })
        );
    }

    await Promise.all(results);

    db.close();
});
```

Comment: thank you for the response, i have implemented this into my code however it is still getting stuck in my `for` loop

Comment: It's not logging anything? It just gets stuck?

Comment: it is uploading documents as it should be, and logging 'Document inserted' however it will not get pass that point once all 16000 docs are done

Comment: "Not get passed"? All it should do after the loop (in the example given) is close the database connection. Put a log there and see if it fires. It should, unless 1 of the insert operations gets stuck and doesn't time out/complete.

Comment: I have just looked into it some more, it is returning a `topology was destroyed` error, any ideas? (I know this is probably an error on my part but im not sure what has caused it)

Comment: I've done some research into using ```await``` in loops, and have edited my answer. This is a better approach.

Comment: Thanks however in this format it just returns 'document not inserted'

Comment: ` MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed` this tells me it is still closing the connection before it can send documents

Comment: Weird, the ```await Promise.all``` should definitely make it wait till all promises in the ```results``` array are resolved.